# Download CSV ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, csv, download

I am trying convert my data and download it to file csv, but seem it's wrong format.
My code look like that.

My response get from service look like this.

I'm sorry if I make confuse for you guys. Please comment bellow to help me :(. Thanks a lot.

Download it to csv and right format

```
  const getDownloadCSV = async (userId: number, orderId: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await downloadCSVOrder(userId, orderId)
      const csv = '\uFEFF' + response
      const encoder = new TextEncoder()
      const blob = new Blob([encoder.encode(csv)], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;',
      })
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.setAttribute('href', url)
      link.setAttribute('download', 'filename.csv')
      link.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
      document.body.removeChild(link)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        openNotification({ type: 'error', description: error.message })
      } else {
        openNotification({ type: 'error', description: 'Some error occurred' })
      }
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfGzG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF4Oe.png)

Right format when I copy response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIQp5.png)

Wrong format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QDtl.png)

Comment: When I copy my response, it's working well. But when I get from response. It's not working right format.

Comment: Specify `endings: "native"` in the `new Blob`options (check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#parameters)).

Comment: "_seem it's wrong format_" what do you mean exactly? When you open the file with MS Excel? Maybe add some additional screenshots.

Comment: I have edited my post and add some image @ghybs

Comment: I give you guys my code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/csv-forked-vcyxgx?file=/src/App.tsx